# How to set user password_life_time for only one user?

Tags: oracle, passwords, sqlplus, lifetime

This statement:

```
ALTER PROFILE DEFAULT LIMIT PASSWORD_LIFE_TIME 180;
```

changes the `password_life_time` value for all users in my profile. But what if I need to change this value for *only one* user?

Would I use something like this?:

```
ALTER username LIMIT PASSWORD_LIFE_TIME UNLIMITED
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't do that directly through `ALTER USER`. You would need to [create a new profile](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/statements_6010.htm), configure that as you need, and then alter the user to pick up that profile.

It would be unusual to have a single user with specific requirements, and in most situations profiles are more flexible and efficient

Comment: but I want to allow users to change their account settings. With your solution I have to create one profile for each user.

Comment: Why would you want users to be able to change their own password lifetime? Doesn't that make having it pointless? It's there to enforce security requirements. If you mean a kind of super user who can change other's accounts, you could have a few profiles with various levels of restriction, and let them pick one, I suppose.